# Select input with Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel

```
{!! Form::select('country',['1' => 'Albania','2'=>'Kosovo','3'=>'Germany','4'=>'France'],null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Select Country']) !!}
```

This type of input doesn't take the values of the array but instead, it takes the pre-default value of option inside select.enter code here

Comment: What's your problem / issue? It isn't really clear what you're having trouble with.

Comment: If l select Germany it doesn't take that value 'Germany' but it takes value 3..

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Form Collective documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists), the first argument of the `Form::select()` is the `name` of the `select` box, the second is an `array` of the `input` values while the third is the `default` value (this could be set to `null`). The fourth is an optional array of attributes/values. 
This should work for you.

```
{!! Form::select('country',['Albania' => 'Albania','Kosovo'=>'Kosovo','Germany'=>'Germany','France'=>'France'],'Kosovo',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Select Country']) !!}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{!! Form::select('country', [null => 'Select Country'] + ['Albania' => 'Albania','Kosovo'=>'Kosovo','Germany'=>'Germany','France'=>'France'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

For more information : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: Still it takes the value of option. For example if i select the first element it takes 1. Thanks anyway!

Comment: i can not understand. you select Albania and it shows what?

Comment: It gets the value 1.